# Which button was pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im making an app  with 4 UIImageView and 4 UIButtons. Each button are connected to a UIAlerView which has an option that opens the photolibrary so the UIImageView can be changed.
My problem is that I dont know how to tell the UIAlertView which UIButton was pressed.

How can I write that which button was pressed?

Comment: There are enough tutorials on the web that cover exactly this topic, work through them and if questions remain, come here again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575037/what-are-resources-for-learning-objective-c/13577666#13577666

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can connect all buttons to another method if you are using interface builder or add them different targets. It will be easier but not very scalable, or it won't be compatible with a dynamic number of buttons.
2. Add the same target & selector to all buttons using:

   ```
   [_yourButton1 addTarget:self
              action:@selector(aButtonTapped:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   ```

   and inside aButton tapped method check which button is tapped and act accordingly:

   ```
   - (void) aButtonTapped:(id) sender{

        if ( sender == _yourButton2) //Do sth
   }
   ```

Using interface builder will be easier in both cases.

Comment: where should I put them?

Comment: The second one is a method of the viewController and the first block can be put anytime after the buttons are initialized, viewDidLoad should be sufficient. But I think you should improve yourself a little bit more.

Comment: But the part _yourButton1, thats should be replaced with my button right ? but should I write the outlet of the button or the action? the action doesnt appear

Comment: You don't need to write an outlet for the button, connecting the actions will be sufficient, unless you want to make changes on the button at runtime

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to do.

In the action if you log the sender, it will show which button was pressed.

```
-(IBAction) myFirstButton: (id) sender {
  NSLog(@"User clicked %@", sender);
  // Do something here with the variable 'sender'
  /*if ( [[sender title] isEqualToString:@"Button 1"] ) { 
        //do whatever you want
  */
}
```

Second way is by Posting and observing Notification.

Comment: Third way is to use google ;)

Comment: I should make this 1st, 2nd SO and 3rd and 4th mine ... lol

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer..vote up , accept etc. Or shoot us with other doubts :p

Comment: Im very new with this so could you please tell me some more about log the sender?

Answer (score 1):

You can add tags to your buttons.